# social meta tags located after </head> tag

Tags: meta-tags, social

During my work, i have faced an issue with a magento site. When i check product social meta-tags  with inspect element they are located inside "head" tag . But when i open  "view the page source" i notice that social meta-tags (for example: "meta property="og:title") are located after "/head".

What to do in this case ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: please update your question with details on how the tags were added

Comment: i am not sure about this, because someone else built the site and i dont know how to find the path...

Comment: They are probably located in a local.xml layout file